# Has lifted or is lifted?

Tags: grammar, phrases, questions

Which is correct?

> Can you imagine the weight that **has** lifted off of her shoulders?

or

> Can you imagine the weight that **is** lifted off of her shoulders?

Comment: Good question, but what’s the context? What tense are you hoping to use, for example?

Comment: @Fivesideddice    Ok lets say this girl has financial support for her studies from someone and her financial burden is reduced. Which one should we use? Is or has? Or are they both interchangeable?

Comment: And also what about has BEEN lifted?   Is there any difference ?

Comment: @anouk - not so fast! A weight that is lifted by someone, or by circumstances, is also one that, from the point of view of the person upon whose shoulders it rested, has lifted.

Comment: You are right. I will remove my comment.